# Excel - removing duplicates with data validation

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I know this issue may sound like something that has been solved a million times, however all of the fixes that I have found haven't helped.

I have a horizontal cell range of numbers which I want to be displayed in a data validation list. Easily enough I can just set the DV list as `=A1:H1`. My issue is that I would then like to remove any duplicate values without creating any new lists of data.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use VBA to do that, but I'm not sure if it can be achieved without VBA

Comment: It would be great if this could be done without using VBA

Comment: I found this link that might be interesting, but honestly speaking, I didn't understand how it works. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/682973-named-range-unique-values.html

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells you want the DV to be applied and run this short macro:

```
Sub uniDV()
    Dim r As Range
        For Each r In Selection
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=unik(Range("A1:H1"))
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Next r
End Sub

Public Function unik(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range
    Set c = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            unik = unik & "," & v
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    unik = Mid(unik, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

The function constructs a comma-separated string and the sub applies the DV.

Comment: If an in-built function is not available then I will be looking for something like this however it is for multiple ranges of data.

I would be looking for something that said "For each cell in range, create data validation list in [specified cell] consisting of unique data from [specified range].. Is this possible?

Comment: @JackCampion  It **is** possible.............we wouuld need to know which ranges to apply the *DV* and which ranges contain the *DV* lists.